# How to concatenate the Checkbox value into one Var in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have check boxes whose value i need to formate into query to send it to server side o button click..If the checkbox is checked i need to add it into query var else ignore ..
Here is my query syntax ..

```
and toc='local' or toc='isd' .
```

Here is my code in html..

```
            <input type="checkbox" name="CallTypeLOCAL" id="local" value="'LOCAL'"/>LOCAL</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CallTypeSTD" id="std" value="'STD'"/>STD</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CallTypeISD" id="isd" value="'ISD'"/>ISD</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CallTypeINETCALL" id="inetcall" value="'INETCALL'"/>INETCALL</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CallTypeINCOMING" id="incoming" value="'INCOMING'"/>INCOMING</label>
```

Any help will be welcomed..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ || http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Why not just build the query when the button is clicked before you send the data to the server?

Comment: @MrGTgo sir i want to do the same build the query and send it to server\

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to accomplish this is to combine the checked values into a bitfield.  I have done this [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe5yA/).  The key is writing a little boolean prototype extension to convert bools to integers and then left shift the result as required

```
Boolean.prototype.intval = function(places)
{
 places = ('undefined' == typeof(places))?0:places; 
 return (~~this) << places
}
```

With that done you simply do

```
var rslt = $('#local').is(':checked').intval();
rslt += $('#std').is(':checked').intval(1);
rslt += $('#isd').is(':checked').intval(2);
rslt += $('#inetcall').is(':checked').intval(3);
rslt += $('#incoming').is(':checked').intval(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").serialize();
```

That would work to get the name value pair of all your checkboxes that are checked.

But why not give all these checkboxes the same class? This way you can do something like this (assuming you gave them all class=someData):

```
    $(".someData:checked").serialize();
```

Also are they enclosed in a form? Then you can just serialize the entire form and it'll be properly encoded and added to the post data

Here's a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayoitzrimz/a5vnd/1)

Comment: Giving them all the same class is a good idea, the same name isn't because it totally changes how they'd interact with your server-side code (you'd have to rewrite it, and that's not necessary).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist That's true in the context of the question. I'll edit and upvote your comment. I personally like using the same name for a group of checkboxes or radio buttons but I should be trying to answer the question specifically

Comment: @mlnyc thank u very much sir ..Sir i want value of the checkbox if it is checked with query like "and toc='checkboxvalue' or toc='checkboxvalue'"